# SQL Server - Order By issue parent child relationship

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I have a database table with the following fields:
DocumentID, ParentID, OrderBy

When the ParentID is not null it matches one DocumentID.
I am trying to group the child documents under the parent documents keeping the OrderBy sort order.

For example:

```
DocumentID  ParentID OrderBy
    36        null     3
    167        75      4
    60        null     8
    75        null     7
```

The correct order would be:

```
3, 7, 4, 8
```

P.S.: I can't use the WITH statement. My client is using an older version of SQL Server (2000).

Comment: How many levels deep does the hierarchy go? If no more than one (i.e. a given row either has a `NULL` ParentID or points to a row that does), then you can sort by `coalesce(ParentID, DocumentID)`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this a try...
It retrieves the parent's OrderBy value if one exists, then sots by that, else it sorts by it's own order by value. As far as I remember, all of this is valid SQL 2000 Syntax

```
SELECTa.*
FROM YourTable a 
ORDER BY ISNULL(
    (SELECT OrderBy 
     FROM YourTable b 
     WHERE a.ParentId = b.DocumentId), 
a.OrderBy), a.ParentId
```

Result

```
DocumentId  ParentId  OrderBy
36          NULL      3
75          NULL      7
167         75        4
60          NULL      8
```